# How to make Grails 3 use plural routes by default

Tags: grails, routes, naming, plural

So I have a Grails (3.2.4) app, but the routes are all set to be *singular* names by default. For example:

```
/product/2
/order/4952
```

I have managed to change the database table naming to use plural using the following in the Product domain class:

```
static mapping = {
    table "products"
}
```

Reading the docs, I also found the following (added to UrlMappings.groovy) to create an alias using plural routes:

```
"/products"(resources:"product")
```

But the singularly-named routes end up still available. So either /product or /products can be used. Is there a way to change the default Grails routes to always use **plural** instead of singular naming convention? That is, a way so I don't have to explicitly write code to define them to be plural.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no way to change the default behavior for url mapping in Grails to use **plural** without you having to explicitly write code to define them.

Comment: What if you defined the controller using a plural name? Wouldn't that work by default? E.g. ProductsController instead of ProductController

Comment: That would still be using the default behavior and not changing it to automatically make it plural. So, if you can change the names of your controllers (and/or domains, depending on how you are doing things) then this might work for you. But again, it's not changing the default behavior, like you asked.